# i'm getting an error when trying to install dependecies in package.json with npm install

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, package.json, sharp

npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path C:\Users\HP\Desktop\workings\alx-files_manager\node_modules\sharp
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c (node install/libvips && node install/dll-copy && prebuild-install) || (node install/can-compile && node-gyp rebuild && node install/dll-copy)
npm ERR! sharp: Downloading https://github.com/lovell/sharp-libvips/releases/download/v8.12.2/libvips-8.12.2-win32-x64.tar.br
npm ERR! sharp: Please see https://sharp.pixelplumbing.com/install for required dependencies
npm ERR! sharp: Installation error: Request timed out

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2024-03-12T17_05_23_036Z-debug-0.log

I expected the package to install successfully

Comment: The error tells about a request timeout, so it can mean you have a network issue, or the server hosting the package you are trying to download is not available maybe.

Answer (score 0):

As the error itself says :  `Installation error: Request timed out`

This indicates that the download process to fetch the package dependencies from GitHub took too long and exceeded a set timeout limit.

This could be caused by various factors, that you can check for :

1. Try checking your internet connection
2. Try switching to a different network (you can also try using mobile data if that helps)
3. Delete `node_modules` folder and the `package-lock.json` file. Then, run the following command:

> npm install